# Ну давай когда-то на выходных пересечемся тогда

Tags: грамматика

I am trying to understand this question. 
Does it mean to find some time to spend during the weekend, or does it mean to go through it, as to make it go away?

Comment: I'm not sure I got "go through it, as to make it go away" part at all.

Comment: Go through -- проходить через что-то (пересекать in its direct meaning.)

Comment: Make it go away -- видимо, пресечь что-то, to stop.

Comment: So that makes sense, and the question doesn't deserve downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In colloquial language:

`Ну давай` when it precedes some action means "let's" or "then let's". Example:

```
-    Ну  давай  колодец  починим,  -  раздражаясь,  сказал капитан. (Ю. И. Болдырев "Приключения Васи Куролесова")
```

"Ну давай колодец починим" means "then let us repair (your) well".

`тогда` means then.

`когда-то на выходных` means at some time at weekend

`пересечёмся` on young people's slang means встретимся (meet in plural and future tense)

So, the whole sentence means "then let us meet some time on weekend".

Comment: Young people? I heard it from anyone; it's not even much of a slang, it's just an informal phrase, and is quite common. Its meaning is easier to grasp making it "[let's make our _paths_] intersect".

Answer (score 2):

Let's meet at some weekend then.

That is the meaning of the phrase. The main difficulty is пересечемся (slang) meaning "to meet" and perhaps давай, which is actually an invitation to start some action.

Answer (score 1):

Literally:
So let's some time later on one of the weekends meet up.

Answer (score -2):

"Ну, давай" usually means "so long, bye". "Пересечёмся" ("we'll cross [each other's way]") is slang for "we'll meet". The whole phrase is very colloquial bordering on teenage slang for "See you later, hope we'll see each other at weekend". "Выходные" is "weekend".

The whole phrase means "Bye, I hope we'll meet at weekend some day".

Comment: "Ну давай" (without comma) can mean "Let's"